# Is it possible to use two file managers at the same time?

Tags: nautilus

I have no problem with Nautilus, but i"m used to Midnight Commander and it would be wonderful if i could have both of them working together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily install it in your system opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

or look for `mc` or midnight commander in the Ubuntu Software Center.

After installing it you can just open the dash and look for it

[image]

and you can pin it to the Unity launcher simply by dragging the Midnight Commander icon to the desired position

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can run as many as you would like.  Examples: **Nautilus, Commander, Dolphin** etc...  Below is a link listing the most common ones used in Linux.

http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/06/20-file-managers-for-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am using Nautilus (default on Ubuntu 11) and Dolphin together and it works perfectly.